# How to fill the overlap parts of 3 arc in pgf/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a picture as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
  \draw(0,0) arc(-90:90:2);
  \draw[dashed](0,0) arc(-90:-270:2);  
  \draw(0,0) arc(180:90:4);
  \draw(0,0) arc(180:90:4);
  \draw[dashed](0,0) arc(-180:90:4);  
  \draw(4,0) arc(-90:-180:4);
  \draw[dashed](4,0) arc(-90:180:4);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now I would draw shadow on the 3 arc overlapped parts, how should I do this?
Just like this picture:

And What if I want to draw line between A-B-C, how should I do?
Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Honestly, it would be quite impossible for shadings having shadows. Anyway, `\clip circle_1;\clip circle_2;\clip circle_3;\fill rectangle;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the shadowing of the fill lines, somethng like this. The fill you can do with some help of `\clip` inside a `scope` environment. To set coordinates at the intersections use the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip(0,2) circle (2);
    \clip(4,0) circle (4);
    \fill[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=red](4,4) circle (4);
  \end{scope}
  %\draw(0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \draw[name path=left](0,0) arc(-90:90:2);
  \draw[dashed](0,0) arc(-90:-270:2);  
  \draw[name path=lower](0,0) arc(180:90:4);
  %\draw(0,0) arc(180:90:4);
  \draw[dashed](0,0) arc(-180:90:4);  
  \draw[name path=upper](4,0) arc(-90:-180:4);
  \draw[dashed](4,0) arc(-90:180:4);  
  %%
  \path [name intersections={of=lower and upper}];
  \coordinate (A) at (intersection-1);
  \path [name intersections={of=left and upper}];
  \coordinate (B) at (intersection-1);
  \path [name intersections={of=left and lower}];
  \coordinate (C) at (intersection-2);
  %%
  \node[left,red] at (A) {A};
  \node[below,red] at (B) {B};
  \node[above,red] at (C) {C};
  %%
  \fill[blue,fill=blue,opacity=0.3] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
  \draw[blue,thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I can't image the power of pgf.